# Night Vision Video: Occupancy Detection using OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, video, raspberry-pi

Using Raspberry Pi NoIR camera, I am trying to do occupancy detection using OpenCV for shared office space.

In order to identify vacant spots, I am using image of empty office space as a background model. Once we have the background model, I  subtract the live video frame from the background image model(using cvAbsDiff) and identify the changes.

I am getting the images using a webcam mounted on the roof. The problem is to identify a person from this angle. When I work with live video, there are subtle variations (changes in chair position, physical objects or variations of camera) which act as noise. I tried using BackgroundSubtractorMOG, MOG2 but MOG and MOG2 can only do differences from a video stream but not using an image reference model.

Any inputs on possible directions will be greatly appreciated. I will be happy to share the technique with you guys that works once I have a working solution. Thanks!

Comment: Try ViBe foreground extraction.